# Creating slugs from graphQL query in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, slug

I am connecting to a database, and this query is showing me the IDs that I want:

```
allSongs {
        edges {
          node {
            id
          }
        }
      }
```

So now I want to be able to load a dynamic page like this:
site.com/song/6

Where the "6" is the id above. It looks like I'll need to create slugs dynamically based on the query, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/

Comment: Yeah, I've read part-seven several times but it's a different scenario that has markdown files in a directory. I'm asking a different question here.

Comment: source can be anything, files/DB/remote CMS, method is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`createPage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/) api in `gatsby-node.js` and create dynamic pages

```
// Create song pages dynamically
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const songTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/songs.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allSongs {
        edges {
          node {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  result.data.allSongs.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/song/${edge.node.id}`,
      component: songTemplate,
    })
  })
}
```